# Linq Lambda Averaging of DataTable Columns - removing 0 values

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatable, average

I am averaging each column in a DataTable and adding those averages to a list.  How can I prevent the average from including values of 0?  I've tried the code below but get an error that the operator `!=`can not be applied to operands of type `object[]` and `int`

```
for (int col = 5; col < DT2.Columns.Count; col++)
{
    double avg = DT2.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(x => 
                     x[DT2.Columns[col]] != DBNull.Value || 
                     x[DT2.Rows[col].ItemArray != 0)
                 .Average(x => double.Parse(x[DT2.Columns[col]].ToString()));
    averages.Add(avg);
}
```

Im starting with col = 5 because I only want to average every column after the fifth column. The data in the columns being averaged is of type double. If I remove the code where Im attempting to remove values of 0, the code runs but if for example I average the first column and the column has 10 rows but 3 of them contain 0, it will add all the rows together and divide by 10 where as I need it to divide by 7

Comment: change the `||` to `&&` `.Where(x => x[DT2.Columns[col]] != DBNull.Value && x[DT2.Rows[col].ItemArray != 0)`

Comment: @Romoku doesn't solve the problem. You're still comparing `ItemArray` with `0`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I'm not quite following his logic (or do I know what his datatable looks like), but maybe `x[col]  != DBNull.Value && x[col] is double && (x[col] as double) != 0`

Comment: Actually it's probably a `string`, so `x[col] != DBNull.Value && x[col].ToString().Trim() != "0"`

Comment: Im starting with col = 5 because I only want to average every column after the fifth column.  The data in the columns being averaged is of type double.  If I remove the code where Im attempting to remove values of 0, the code runs but if for example I average the first column and the column has 10 rows but 3 of them contain 0, it will add all the rows together and divide by 10 where as I need it to divide by 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the columns inline if you just want the columns after 5.

```
var columns = DT2.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(5);
var rows = DT2.AsEnumerable();

IEnumerable<double> rowAverages =
      rows
        .Select(r =>
            columns
                .Where(c =>
                    r[c] != DBNull.Value &&
                    r[c] is double &&
                    ((double)r[c]) > 0)
                .Select(c =>
                    (double)r[c]))
        .Select(r =>
            r.Any() ? r.Average() : 0);

IEnumerable<double> columnAverages =
      columns
        .Select(c =>
            rows.Where(r =>
                    r[c] != DBNull.Value &&
                    r[c] is double &&
                    ((double)r[c]) > 0)
                .Select(r => (double)r[c]))
        .Select(c => c.Any() ? c.Average() : 0);
```

Comment: The line `(r[c] as double) != 0))` gives the error "The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('double' is a non-nullable type).

Comment: Ok.  That doesnt give me any errors, but how can I add the output to my list?

Comment: This provides no errors at compile time, however when I run the code the list doesnt populate.  When I debug and step into the list and look under 'Values' it states "cannot convert type double[] into system.exception

Comment: If I replace your `IEnumerable<double> averages =` with ` averages.AddRange(` I get the error "Sequence contains no elements"

Comment: I'm not sure what what could be causing it. Try changing the last line from `r.Average()` to `r.Any() ? r.Average() : 0 `. Check my edit for reference.

Comment: Note: `r => r.DefaultIfEmpty().Average()` is bit cleaner IMO.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Well there's no reason to call average if there aren't any elements, but I agree it does look cleaner. If only there was control flow with extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the task. First, create a function that returns the values in one column:

```
IEnumerable<object> GetColumnValues(DataTable dt, int columnIndex)
{
    if (dt.Columns.Count < columnIndex + 1)
        yield break;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (row[columnIndex] != DBNull.Value)
            yield return row[columnIndex];
    }
}
```

Now you've got a way to get column values, next you can decide what to do with them. For instance, iterate over your columns and per column do:

```
var avg =  GetColumnValues(DT2, colIndex).OfType<double>()
           .Where(d => d > 0).Average();
```